# Field 'dynamicLibrary' has not been initialized.) in dart_vlc package

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-getx, dart-null-safety

while Im trying initilizing the controller it didnt initilize and give me this error
`LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'dynamicLibrary' has not been initialized.)`

Ihad tried to initilize like this

```
late Player player;

@override
void oninit(){
player=Player(id: 2569, commandlineArguments: ['Xvideo ']);
}
```

and try this

```
Player ? player;

@override
void oninit(){

player=Player(id: 2569, commandlineArguments: ['Xvideo ']);
}
```

It works on dekstop when I run it on android It didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void main() async {
  await DartVLC.initialize (useFlutterNativeView: true);
  runApp (const VideoPlayer());
}
```

**use this in main**

Answer (score 1):

The package `dart_vlc` doesn't support mobile as of today. Consider using an alternative for mobile platforms :

- [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)
- [flutter_vlc_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player)